# How to use global functions VUE 2 CLI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

few of my components are using same functions, is there a way how don't to copy code to each component but use it globally...?
If you just put the function in the App.vue, then it is still not available in the component...

Comment: Typically this is done by `import`ing js modules. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Look at Vue mixins.

Answer (score 1):

Write a separate page with the same functionality, and then introduce it where it is needed.

```
<template>
    <div class='demo'>
        <module></module>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import  module from './components/module'
export default {
    components:{module},
data() {
return {

};
},
methods: {

},
created() {

},
mounted() {

},
}
</script>
<style lang='less' scoped>

</style>
```